# How can I change the color of a pixel with coordinates x and y in the image?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX9Mz.png)

How can I change the color of a pixel with coordinates x and y in the image?

**How can I change the color of a pixel with only the coordinates (x, y) of the image I have? (only 1 pixel).**

```
private static bool boyalganmi(int x, int y)
        {
            //ushbu nuqtalar 2480x3508 o'lchamdagi list uchun
            (int, int)[] nuqta = new[] { (x, y), (x, y - 18), (x + 13, y - 13), (x + 18, y),
                (x + 13, y + 13), (x, y + 18), (x - 13, y + 13), (x - 18, y), (x - 13, y - 13) };
            int oq = 0, qora = 0, boshqa = 0;
            foreach ((int, int) nuqtaItem in nuqta)
            {
                var imageXY = Image.GetPixel(nuqtaItem.Item1%2480, nuqtaItem.Item2%3508);
                if (imageXY.R > 225 && imageXY.G > 225 && imageXY.B > 225)
                {
                    oq++;
                    Color green = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 128, 0);
                    Image.SetPixel(nuqtaItem.Item1, nuqtaItem.Item2, Color.Green);

                }
                else if (imageXY.R < 10 && imageXY.G < 10 && imageXY.B < 10)
                {
                    qora++;
                    Color red = Color.FromArgb(255, 225, 0, 0);
                    Image.SetPixel(nuqtaItem.Item1, nuqtaItem.Item2, Color.Red);
                }
                else { boshqa++; MessageBox.Show($"RGB({imageXY.R},{imageXY.G},{imageXY.B})"); }
            }
            //MessageBox.Show($"oq={oq}, qora={qora}, boshqa={boshqa}");
            return oq > qora;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the image to bitmap. You can take it as a picture again after making changes. Let's see my code. It works good)
Source code: https://github.com/Nodirbek-Abdulaxadov/SetPixelColor

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ColorPixel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        Color clr;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ofd.Filter = "jpg files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|png files(*.png)|*.png|jpeg files(*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ofd.FileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                clr = colorDialog1.Color;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ofd.FileName is not null)
            {
                Bitmap image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
                Random random = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
                {
                    int X = random.Next(image.Width);
                    int Y = random.Next(image.Height);
                    image.SetPixel(X, Y, clr);
                }

                pictureBox2.Image = image;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Form1 visibility]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).